# Functional integral for unconstrained superfields

Tags: gauge-theory, path-integral, supersymmetry, gauge-invariance, superspace-formalism

### Context

In [this](https://inspirehep.net/literature/202612) paper by Srivastava (also in his book "Supersymmetry, Superfields and Supergravity"), he proposes the functional integral for a chiral superfield $\Phi$. In order to work with unconstrained superfields, he defines superfield potentials $S,\bar{S}$  so that

$$\begin{align}\Phi&=-\frac{1}{4}\bar{D}^2S\\ \bar\Phi&=-\frac{1}{4}D^2\bar{S}.\end{align}$$

There is gauge-invariance $S\to S+\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\bar{\Sigma}^{\dot{\alpha}}$ , $\bar{S}\to\bar{S}+D^\alpha\Sigma_\alpha$ with $\Sigma_\alpha$ a spinor superfield, so he uses a gauge-fixing term

$$I_{\text{gf}}=\xi\int d^8z\bar{S}\square(1-P_1) S=-\xi\int d^8z(\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\bar S)\left(\frac{3}{16}\bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}D^\alpha+\frac{1}{4}D^\alpha \bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}\right)(D_\alpha S)\tag{GF}$$

where $P_1=\frac{D^2\bar{D}^2}{16\square}$. He claims that the gauge-fixing functions are $\mathcal{F}_\alpha=D_\alpha S$ , $\bar{\mathcal{F}}_\dot{\alpha}=\bar{D}_\dot{\alpha}\bar{S}$, and that ghosts decouple.

---

### What I (believe I) know

I'm a bit familiar with gauge-fixing and ghosts in functional integral for abelian gauge theories. For example for $U(1)$

$$\mathcal{Z}[J]=\int\mathcal{D}A~~\det\left[\partial_\mu\left(\frac{\delta g}{\delta A_\mu}\right)\right]~~\delta[g(A)]~~e^{\textstyle -I[A]-J\cdot A},\tag{1}$$

where $g(A)=0$ is the gauge condition.

Ghosts show up from the Faddeev-Popov determinant

$$\det\left[\partial_\mu\left(\frac{\delta g}{\delta A_\mu}\right)\right]=\int\mathcal{D}c\mathcal{D}\bar{c}~e^{\textstyle-\int d^4x~\bar{c}\partial_\mu\!\!\left(\frac{\delta g}{\delta A_\mu}\right)\!c},\tag{FP}$$

so if $g(A)$ is just linear in $A_\mu$ (in QED it can be chosen so), ghosts decouple and we can ignore them.

In QED, in order to use the [$R_\xi$ gauges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R%CE%BE_gauges), one uses $g(A)=\partial_\mu A^\mu-\lambda(x)$ and does a "gaussian average" over $\lambda(x)$

$$\mathcal{Z}'[J]=\int \mathcal{D}\lambda e^{\textstyle -\frac{1}{2\xi}\int d^4x \lambda(x)^2}\mathcal{Z}[J].\tag{2}$$

Integrating over $\lambda$ taking into account the functional delta of $(1)$ is like adding the $R_\xi$ gauge-fixing term to the action.

---

### Questions

1. How can we see that (GF) is a suitable gauge-fixing term?
2. What would be the equivalent expresion to $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $S,\bar{S}$?

I suppose that having the second one answered it should be clear for me which is the relation between what he calls "gauge-fixing functions" and my $g(A)$, and how ghosts decouple.

---

### Update: Possible answer to 2.

Reading [these lessons](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108200) (part $6.2\text{.c}$) I have a proposal for my second question.

Since the gauge transformations we are dealing with involve two superfield spinorial components, we need two "$g()$"s: $g_\alpha(S),~\alpha=1,2$ (the same for $\bar{S}$), so the equivalent expression to $(1)$ is

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{Z}[J,\bar{J}]=\int\mathcal{D}S \mathcal{D}\bar{S} ~&\delta\big[g_\alpha(S)\big]~\delta\big[\bar{g}_{\dot{\alpha}}(\bar{S})\big]\det\left[D^\beta\left(\frac{\delta g_\alpha}{\delta S}\right)\right]\det\left[\bar{D}_{\dot{\beta}}\left(\frac{\delta \bar{g}_{\dot{\alpha}}}{\delta \bar{S}}\right)\right]\times \\ &\times e^{\textstyle -I[S,\bar{S},J,\bar{J}]}\end{align}\tag{3}$$

Now we get an equivalent expression to $(2)$ averaging with

$$\mathcal{Z}'[J,\bar{J}]=\int \mathcal{D}\chi\mathcal{D}\bar{\chi}~e^{\textstyle -\xi\int d^8z \bar{\chi}_{\dot{\alpha}}M^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\chi_{\alpha}}\mathcal{Z}[J,\bar{J}].\tag{4}$$

If we now choose

$$g_{\alpha}(S)=\overbrace{D_{\alpha}S}^{\text{Srivastava's  } \mathcal{F}_\alpha}-\chi_\alpha\\
\bar{g}_{\dot{\alpha}}(\bar{S})=\underbrace{\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\bar{S}}_{\text{Srivastava's  } \bar{\mathcal{F}}_{\dot{\alpha}}}-\bar{\chi}_{\dot{\alpha}}\tag{5}$$

(now I see how ghosts decouple) and integrate $\chi$ and $\bar{\chi}$ using the functional deltas, we get the gauge fixing term

$$I_{\text{gf}}=\xi\int d^8 z~\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\bar{S} M^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}D_{\alpha}S,$$

which is the same as $(\text{GF})$ if

$$M^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}=-\frac{3}{16}\bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}D^\alpha-\frac{1}{4}D^\alpha \bar{D}^{\dot{\alpha}}.\tag{6}$$

If this is correct, now my question is

- Why can we average with $(4)$ and choose $M^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}$ as in $(6)$? (In the lessons I linked they chpose another $M$)